# Trying to return an array from Redux store, but returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to return an fetched array from Redux storage, but returning an empty array. By the way fetch is working well. I can't find a mistake

Probably the mistake is in reducer or i just have it in { connect }

fetching data from tmdb here, return array

```js
action.js

export function itemFetchMovies() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                let movies = [];

                let currentCount = 1;
                function makeCounter() {
                    return function() {
                        return currentCount++;
                    };
                }

                let counter = makeCounter();
                for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                    let image_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data.results[i].poster_path;
                    movies.push({
                        key: {i},
                        number: counter(),
                        poster: <img
                            src={image_url}
                            alt="new"
                            style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                        />,
                        title: data.results[i].original_title,
                        year: data.results[i].release_date
                    })
                }
                console.log(movies);
                dispatch(
                            {
                                type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
                                payload: movies
                            }
                        );
            });
    }
}
```

Redux reducer, just want to exchange initial state to fetched data

```js
reducer.js

const initalState = {
    list: []
};


export function items(state = initalState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                list: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state ;
    }
}
```

on componentDidMount call my fetch function via states, use { connect } to connect porps and store

```js
App.js


class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovie();
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


App.propTypes = {
    fetchMovie: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    list: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        list: state.list,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchMovie: () => dispatch(itemFetchMovies())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

```js
index.js

const store = createStore(items, applyMiddleware(thunk));
console.log(store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Where is this empty array appearing in your code? In App.js?

Answer (score -1):

Let me clear you on this,

**Issue**:

connect only compare the shallow change of the data, means 1 level depth change.
In your case you are changing in movies array which connect is not able to get and It does not rerender itself.

Any object or array change in depth like you did will not trigger rerender because connect will not know the values inside the object/array is changed.

**Solution**:

You need to add the counter variable, which only increment itself in the reducer and just get into mapStateToProps as prop, which you do not need to use anywhere else just to let the connect know that you have changed something inside the array/object.

**in reducer**

return like this

```
dispatch(
 {
  type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
  payload: movies,
  counter: state.counter++,
 }
);
```

in **container**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        list: state.list,
        counter: state.counter,
    };
};
```

hope this gives you the help and solution.

Comment: You're technically correct with the issue part, but it does not apply here. `state.list` is a different object every time the reducer is called, so shallow comparison is enough.

Your solution though, apart from mixing up the action and the reducer, is wrong. You're supposed to not mutate the existing state in the reducer and then you don't have to do any counter tricks. Read more here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects